# Linux crashed menu access

Tags: gnome

I pressed the key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> on my Ubuntu with a browser window open, and it just crashed gnome. How can I get my system back without restarting the machine?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> which brings up the "Run" dialog, enter the letter `r` (which stands for "restart") and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: screenshot of the run dialog with the letter r entered]

This will restart Gnome without affecting your session or restarting your machine.